# Powershell script to delete specifically named files

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that runs as a scheduled task each night. It works great. 
What I want to do now is use the same script on a different machine to delete specific log files older than x days.
Path to the log files: C:\Company\Logs
There are 4 different log files located here. I need to be able to delete each type independently and send the same type of report that is already in the script.

main.log.date.txtlog

companyname.date.txtlog

dupdump.txt

sfsync.date.txt

Here is the script I have that does currently work.

```
dir C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 -recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer -AND $_.lastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) } | select LastWriteTime,@{n="Path";e={convert-path $_.PSPath}} | tee C:\LogCleanup\deleted.txt | Remove-Item -force

$filename = "C:\LogCleanup\deleted.txt"
$smtpserver = “smtp.company.net”
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($filename)
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $True
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“monitor@company.net”, “password”);  # Put username without the @GMAIL.com or – @gmail.com
$msg.From = “DeletedFilesLog@company.net”
$msg.To.Add(”is@company.net")
$msg.Subject = “The IIS log files in the attached file have been deleted.”
$msg.Body = “The IIS log files on MACHINE NAME have been deleted. See the attached file to view     the log files that were deleted today”
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: Do you have a question about something?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work, but you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How do I setup the script to delete specific files? I don't want all the files deleted just the main.log.date.txtlog every 7 days. Then the companyname.date.txtlog every 30 or 60 days.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$time = "-7"    
$filename = main.log.date.txtlog
Get-ChildItem "\\$PATH" -Recurse | Where {$_.creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays($time)} | Remove-Item -Include $filename -Force
```

$Time determines how old an file must be before it will be deleted.
$filename is the exact filename, whatever it is called.

Comment: I just need to add this to the current script?

Comment: Basically yes, set the time how it pleases you. And adapt the \\$PATH to a path you have. That should do it then.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answere. Otherwise ask more.